# Read folder and display files in UITableView

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I want my app to read a specific folder, and show the files in a UITableView.

I have this code, where it should read the folder called DOKS, but I cant get the file title to show on the textLabel.
Can someone help me? It will super ;-)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Initialize table data


    NSError *error = nil;

    NSString *yourFolderPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]
                                stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"doks"];

    NSArray  *yourFolderContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]
                                    contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:yourFolderPath error:&error];

        recipes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:yourFolderContents, nil];
}


- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [recipes count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"RecipeCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [recipes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're setting an *array within an array* to `recipes`, not the contents array its self.

```
recipes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:yourFolderContents, nil];
```

Instead, try this:

```
recipes = [NSArray arrayWithArray:yourFolderContents];
```

Comment: It didn't do anything :-(

Comment: Try reloading the table view after you set the recipes?

Comment: What do you mean by reloading? How? (sorry i'm new to this code)
When I try it, it highlights this line:
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

And under it, it says: Local declaration of 'tableView' hids instance variable

Comment: And theres is nothing, when I run the app... My folder doks contains 2 pdf files, name test1.pdf and test2.pdf, so I would like it to show those 2 files in the tableview ;-)

Answer (score 0):

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); //create an array and store result of our search for the documents directory in it

```
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; //create NSString object, that holds our exact path to the documents directory

NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"YOUR_FOLDER_NAME"];

NSError * error;
NSArray * directoryContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:dataPath error:&error];
NSMutableArray *filenameArray = [NSMutableArray array];
//if you want to retrive any specific format files
for(NSString *filename in directoryContents) {
    if ([[filename pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"txt"]) {
        [filenameArray addObject:filename];
    }

}
```

And after than you have list of all filenames in filenameArray.

See if it works for you.

Comment: I can't get it to work, it wont build the app, and is shows me this line, with green background:

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

And under it, is says; Thread 11: breakpoint 1.1

Any idea what to do??

Comment: And sorry, but i'm new to this type of code... ;-) Hope you will help anyway?